# Navigation xBap problem with frames

Tags: wpf, navigation, xbap, frames

I have a problem in navigation in xBap

I created two pages (Page1 and Page2)

Page1 have one button for navigation to Page 2

```
    <Button Height="23" Width="76" Name="button1" Click="button1_Click">Page2</Button>
```

---

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService n = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(sender as Button);
    n.Navigate(new Uri("Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

in Page2 there is a frame without any source

```
<Frame Margin="0,90,0,0"/>
```

After running application, and navigating to page2, the navigation will work normally,

but when I press Go Back in browser, then press button1 again

The browser will show this message

[image](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/ccafc92a67.jpg)

Note: in some cases you need to repeat trying

Any help !!

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

since your Browser crashes, i suggest this is some bug in one of the following Components:

- Browser (IE in this Case)
- XBAP Addon/Plugin (yes, there is some kind of plugin which is installed silently within browsers on .NET Framework installation)

I bet, this cannot be solved programmatically... I'd suggest the following:

- try to reproduce in different environment (different IE Version, OS etc.)
- reinstall .NET Framework and ensure you have the latest, stable final version
- do same with Internet Explorer
- Firefox has XBAP support as well - try in firefox

If it works in other environments, your users should have no problems with this setup.

Hope this helps,

Best regards
Thomas